# How to create a method that governs all subclasses in Java

Tags: java, class

In Java I'm creating a class called Room. Room is further divided into two types of rooms: a subclass called largeRoom and a subclass called smallRoom. I'm trying to write a mostExpensive() method that will tell me which room was the mostExpensive() to build. 
I know that if smallRoom and largeRoom were instances of Room it would be easy: I would simply declare the method as static. However I'm not sure how to achieve this same effect with subclasses. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: But SmallRoom and LargeRoom are most certainly instances of Room.

Comment: In this case they're subclasses of Room. Room is an abstract class

Comment: So what? They still are instances of Room

Comment: How can they be instances of room.. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated

Comment: But their non-abstract subclasses can.

Comment: _instance_ == `instanceof` returns true

Comment: An object of class X is an instance of X, any of X's superclasses and interfaces implemented by X, directly or by inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being `static` or not have no direct link to super and sub classes.

`static` members are members which belongs to the `class` and not a specific `object`.

For creating **room class**, you can do something like this:

```
class Room{  //can be declared as abstract
    int cost;
    public int getCost(){return cost;}
}

class largeRoom extends Room{
    //inherit cost from Room class
}

class smallRoom extends Room{
    //inherit cost from Room class    
}
```

> write a mostExpensive() method that will tell me which room was the mostExpensive() to build.

This method needs to compare a collection of Room objects, thus unlikely that you will be creating this method within the Room classes itself.

If you used an ArrayList to store the collection of Rooms.

```
public Room mostExpensive(ArrayList<Room> allRooms)
{
    Room mostExpensiveRoom;  
    int max = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<allRooms.size(); x++)
        if(allRooms.get(x).getCost() > max){
            mostExpensiveRoom = allRooms.get(x);
            max = allRooms.get(x).getCost();}
    return  mostExpensiveRoom;
}
```

This shows how you can make use of the `mostExpensive()` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Room> allRooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
    allRooms.add(new smallRoom());
    allRooms.add(new largeRoom());

    Room mostExpensiveRoom = mostExpensive(allRooms);
}
```

If you do not want to iterate through the collection manually searching for the most expensive room, you may let Room class implement `comparable` and sort your room collection then get the first/last record from the sorted collection. I doubt you will do that, but that is one alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could write this, in Room, like this, assuming you have an abstract method cost, implemented as required by SmallRoom and LargeRoom:

```
public static Room mostExpensive( Collection<Room> allMyRooms ){
    int max = 0;
    Room mostExp = null;
    for( Room room: allMyRooms ){
        if( room.cost() > max ){
            max = room.cost();
            mostExp = room;
        }
    }
    return mostExp;
}
```

I'm assuming that mostExpensive must be applied to a collection of rooms:

```
List<Room> someRooms = ...;
Room top = Room.mostExpensive( someRooms );
```

Comment: So in this case would all of the subclasses need to call super.mostExpensive? Or would they be able to simply call mostExpensive?

Comment: I have assumed that mostExpensive must compare a collection of rooms to determine the one with the highest cost. See answer, for how to call.

Comment: Okay so I think this answers my question. So pretty much if you create a static variable in a class, that static variables governs all of the sub classes because sub classes are technically instances of a particular class. Is that correct?

Comment: "static variable governs subclasses"? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: When I declare a static variable. And I change that variable in the subclass, will it be changed in the superclass?

Comment: You can change the single variable that is declared as static in some class from wherever it is *visible*: always from within the class where it is declared, from a subclass if it is protected or public, from anywhere if it is public, etc.

Comment: The wording "change in the subclass...changed in the superclass" is somewhat askew. If you change it, it is changed. From where is irrelevant.

Comment: @aaa If you declare the static variable in the child class, the parent class can't access it. With that, it is impossible to change it in the parent class since the parent class do not "possess" that variable in the first place.

Comment: @user3437460 This is incorrect. If you declare a static variable as public in *any* class, it can be accessed from *anywhere* - parent, child or sibling class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably implement comparators and call collections.sort.  then you could grab the cheapest (first), most expensive (last), or add comparators for other metrics.
sorry, i'm getting paid to work so cannot include code example :)